# Ruby On Rails; undefined method `comments'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a comment association with the user table, but when I go to the rails console and do try to see if it works, it gives me the following error:

```
user = User.first
user.comments

undefined method `comments'
```

Below is the code that i'm using.

```
  class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
   def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :description
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
   end
  end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :username
    t.string :email

    t.timestamps
  end
 end
end


class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :comments
end
```

Im using the latest version of ruby.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any records in the User table? What does `User.first` return?

Comment: Hello @MrYoshiji @moveson

User.first
<User id: 1, username: "john", email: "carma", created_at: "2017-11-02 18:49:02", updated_at: "2017-11-02 18:49:02">

User.first.comments
NoMethodError: undefined method `comments' for #<User:0x4535058>

I'm using RubyMine, in case that matters.

Comment: did you reload your console after creating this relationships between user and comments? (type `reload!` in the IRB or `exit` and then `rails c` again)

Comment: doing reload! worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Rails has an autoloading thing which allows you to update a file (user model for example) and then "experience" the changes in your web app without rebooting the server. This is not true in the rails' console context. You have to manually `reload!` it or eventually close & reopen

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for undefined method error,
may be you have pending migrations 
run this command

> rails db:migrate